# Analysing code - I can't find source how its written

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know that my question may be annoying because I'm asking about something which is easy for you and of course I can check it by myself but it's too hard for me. I can find the width and height of the div, find the background color and font, but I can't find the code to do the thing you can find here:
http://easyelo.com/
In the FAQ, near the bottom of the page, you click `>>` and it shows additional text with an explanation.
I have no idea how to check where it is doing this. Can someone help me please?

```
<div class="more" style="font-family: arial; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
                <i style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 15px;font-family:arial;">Sorry, we don’t do any jobs until they are paid for; however, we do allow you to pay in increments as small as 10 euro. </i>
                </div>
```

Comment: Looks like an accordion to me http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/

Comment: This solution on easyelo.com is even simplier, just [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) from jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy solution:

Use the following code to create the elements:

```
<div id="mainLine">The immediately visible part of the thing here. <a href="#" id="more">>></a>
<p id="hiddenText">This thing appears and disappears as you click the '>>' at the end.</p>
```

And use this jQuery script to hide the element when the page loads and then display it only when the '>>' is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hiddenText").hide();});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#more").click(function(){
    $("#hiddenText").slideToggle("slow"); }
                 );
});
```

And if you are interested, here is the CSS that removes the underline from the '>>':

```
a
{
 text-decoration: none; /* I'm trying to make it look more like the original */
 }
```

You can find a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/2b7Vp/

This is my first answer on SO & I hope this helps you (partly stolen from @Pavel Sterba's comment. Thanks!).